# Linear mapping rank question

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let $X:U \rightarrow V$ be linear, where $U, V$ are vector spaces. And $Y: T \rightarrow T$ be linear, and $\ker(Y)=\{\vec{0}_T\}$. Prove $rank(Y \circ X)=rank(X)$.

I started by doing an example. Let $X: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$. This means $X(\begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\\ c\\ \end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\\ \end{bmatrix}$

$Y: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R^2}$.

Then it's obvious $Y(\begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\\ \end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\\ \end{bmatrix}$ for any number $a$. This also satisfies the condition $\ker(Y)=\{\vec{0}_T\}$. Then  $rank(Y \circ X)=rank(Y(X(\begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\\ c\\ \end{bmatrix})))=rank(Y\begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\\ \end{bmatrix}))$, which is the same as $rank(X(\begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\\ c\\ \end{bmatrix}))$.

I think the key to proving this is $Y: T \rightarrow T$ does nothing to the linear mapping. How do I generalize this?

Comment: I'm confused about the composition. The domain of $Y$ is $T$ but the codomain of $X$ is $V$, so how can we compose? Is $V$ contained in $T$?

Comment: Your example is also not necessarily correct. It's not necessarily the case that $Y$ is the identity map; there are other maps with trivial kernel. What if $Y$ maps $\vec v$ to $2\vec v$? Once the type-checking issue in Micheal Morrow's comment is resolved, the rank-nullity theorem (https://brilliant.org/wiki/rank-nullity-theorem/) might be of interest.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hints.